# Irreducible Element

Tags: commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

Following a discussion with a friend of mine, we would like to ask:

Is $xy$ considered irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

It admits a factorisation $xy=(x)(y)$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ so I am inclined to say no, but my friend thinks otherwise.

Thanks in advance!

A very stupid question, I know - I apologise!

Comment: Does your friend have a justification for their position?

Comment: Can you apply the definition of irreducible element here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom there's no real justification other than it just should 'seem' irreducible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$xy$ is certainly not irreducible, it's a product of $x,y \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, which are both *non-units* of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (exercise). So it's reducible by definition and so by simple 2-valued logic "*not* irreducible.

Comment: There's a big gap: viz. one has to *prove* that $x,y$ are (nonzero) *nonunits* in $\,\Bbb C[x,y].\,$ Of course that's not too difficult here (but may be highly nontrivial in other rings).

Comment: @BillDubuque I realised this later. I'll add it in. thx.